# Tracking Transparency alert not appearing

Tags: react-native, expo

I installed expo-tracking-transparency:
`expo install expo-tracking-transparency`
Copied the following code from Expo into my React Native project:

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { requestTrackingPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-tracking-transparency';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        console.log('Yay! I have user permission to track data');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Tracking Transparency Module Example</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I copied the plugin into my app.json:

```
  "expo": {
      ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

However I am not seeing the alert. This code works in their Snack example. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the issue:

> The system remembers the user’s choice and doesn’t prompt again unless a user uninstalls and then reinstalls the app on the device.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/tracking-transparency/#hooks